# How to pause a video after a certain time? and play it again the remaining - video.js

Tags: javascript, video.js

I used the following to pause the video after x seconds

```
var pausetime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds

var myPlayer = videojs('example_video_1');

myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if (myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime) {
        myPlayer.pause();
    }
});
```

Here after pause the video I have to display the popup message. It need to be closed after 5 seconds and play the video again from the paused time(i.e play it again from where it is stopped. ).

How to achieve this. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if (myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime) {
        myPlayer.pause();
        setTimeout(function(){
            myPlayer.play()
        },5000)
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
isPause = 0;
var pausetime = 2; // stop at 2 seconds
var myPlayer = videojs('example_video_1');

myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function(e) {
    if( isPause == 0 && ( myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime ) ){
        myPlayer.pause();
        wait();
    }
});

function wait(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        isPause = 1;
        myPlayer.play();
    },5000)
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It pause the video after n sec. after timeout of 5sec it play for a second, and it again paused.

Comment: it's your pausetime, change your pausetime after myPlayer.pause().  pausetime=0

Comment: Sry pausetime= you video time length

Comment: I think, if i set pausetime= you video time lengtg , then the video will be completely played. and then after 5 sec it replay the video. But mu question is refer this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168018/how-to-pause-a-video-after-a-certain-time-and-play-it-again-the-remaining-vid[/link]